# Understanding Suurballe's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have been looking at the Suurballe node-disjoint algorithm, which is illustrated here:

http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Disjoint_Path_Finding

What I am a bit unsure about here is "Step 4". So before that each node in the first shortest path is duplicated/divided into an in and out version of itself. And after that a new path is calculated. However, I can't seem to figure out what happens in Step 4. How are the in and out nodes translated into the original nodes seen in the first shortest path ? I mean, what am I supposed to add up here ? Is `D_in` to `E_out` path equal to just `D` = `E`, or...?

Comment: Is this the same algorithm as described [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm)? If so, can you understand the Wikipedia description better?